# Catch-all proxy Spring Boot endpoint needs RAW request body/content

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a catch-all request mapping in my controller (Spring Boot 1.5.8). Basically any unmatched request goes here, and is passed through to another destination, and the response is returned.

This is working fine for requests with text-based content e.g. `application/json`. However, for `multipart/form-data`, there is no feasible way for me to get access to the *raw* request body because the input stream has already been consumed by Tomcat and/or Spring.

- I don't want Tomcat to do anything with the multipart data
- I don't want Spring to do anything with the multipart data
- I just want a plain ol' `InputStream` which has yet to be read, so I can literally pipe it onward

```java
@RequestMapping
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> proxy(
    @RequestHeader HttpHeaders requestHeaders,
    HttpServletRequest request,
    InputStream data)
{
    // data is already consumed, cannot forward on :(
}
```

I've read [something about *HiddenHttpMethodFilter*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5676) and something about Tomcat consuming the body if it's of content type `multipart/form-data` or `application/www-form-urlencoded`. But not really sure what to do here or how to disable such functionality.

Comment: Maybe take a look at a [caching response wrapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingResponseWrapper.html). Generally speaking Spring supports wrapping all sorts of `InptuStream/OutputStream`, even for `RestTemplate`. The wrapper seems to only work in a filter though

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/int128/e47217bebdb4c402b2ffa7cc199307ba) code looks promising too

Comment: Thanks. FYI the first comment is dealing with caching responses, not requests, so that won't work. The second may be a good starting point; perhaps I can make this work with a filter...

Comment: Oh I misread your question right there, glad something helped you though